# multi_match for _search in elasticsearch is returning all items in my index

Tags: elasticsearch

Here's my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "use_dis_max": false,
      "query": "xxxinvalidqueryxxx",
      "fields": [
        "Title",
        "IsOriginalContent",
        "TextContent"
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {},
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": "desc"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, no matter what query I enter, it returns all items in my index.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `IsOriginalContent` is a boolean field.  No idea why, but when I remove it, everything works correctly.  It's as if searching a boolean field for text always returns 'true' with some very low score.

When I remove any boolean fields from the field list, queries work as expected.